# Delete duplicate Trello cards?

Tags: trello-cards

At times I have duplicate cards(or copies of) on different lists.  Is there a way to do the following:

1. update one card which updates all duplicate cards
2. Delete/Archive one card which will apply the changes to all cards.

Answer (score 1):

While card syncing isn't a native feature of Trello, you can add a
link to the [original card](http://help.trello.com/article/824-sharing-links-to-cards-and-boards) on the new card so that you can refer
back to it easily. When you attach a link to a Trello card on another
card, it will display a preview of that card, and will show which
board and list it belongs to:

You can also click on the "Connect cards" link to make it a 2-way
link, so that both cards link to each other.

Additionally, there are a few third-party Power-Ups that can help you
keep cards in sync. You can read more about those here:

- [Cardsync](http://info.trello.com/power-ups/cardsync)
- [Unito](https://info.trello.com/power-ups/unito)
- [Board Sync by Unito](https://info.trello.com/power-ups/unito/board-sync)

Answer (score 0):

[Cardsync](http://info.trello.com/power-ups/cardsync) seems to be the most efficient, straight forward and cheapest way to do it.

It also syncs everything including labels, attachments comments etc..

The developer who developed this is quite responsive to new feature requests and is quick to support any issues faced...

I've tried the other ones recommended by Trello [here](https://help.trello.com/article/1097-mirroring-cards), but found card-sync to be the best for my needs.